# How do I attach the Visual Studio Code debugger to Godot

Tags: godot, visual-studio-code

At 3.0 Godot now supports C# and encourages the use of Visual Studio Code to edit this code.

It is not clear how to attach VS Code so that we an apply breakpoints and debug a project at runtime.

I am running:

- A recent build of Godot from master (b49ca94 with mono for 64-bit windows)
- Visual Studio Code 1.21.0 with these extenstions

  - C# 1.14
  - Mono Debug 0.15.8
- Mono 5.10.0

Comment: Just did a quick seach and found [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2017/12/21/Godot-Development-Using-Visual-Studio-Code-and-C.aspx) tutorial on making VSCode work nicely with Godot and C#. In the comments I found [this](http://disq.us/p/1ora528). It sounds like there isn't an easy way to do this yet. That doesn't mean that it can't be done, but it will probably be a lot more complex than just checking a couple settings. I have a feeling it would require building a plugin for both programs, so that the breakpoint api can be exposed and then accessed by VSCode.

Comment: These days I use [C# Tools for Godot](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neikeq.godot-csharp-vscode). Then again, than answer is better fit for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh, I hadn't heard Neikeq released some official tooling!

Comment: If you post that comment in the answer box, I will edit my question to be more version agnostic and we can call it answered.  Thanks.